# Payload invalid when calling flow's API with Postman

Tags: corda

**Corda OS 4.3-RC01**

I have an initiating flow that sends a `String` parameter; inside the responding flow it queries its vault to get the `AccountInfo` that has the `name` attribute with the received value and return a `List` with the results.
This works fine when I run flow tests, but when I run the nodes locally and run my webserver then call the API using Postman, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Payload invalid
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.checkPayloadIs(InternalUtils.kt:531) ~[corda-core-4.3-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:56) ~[corda-node-4.3-RC01.jar:?]
```

So when I inspected the method causing the problem (`InternalUtils.checkPayloadIs()`), I noticed that when I run the flow tests (which don't throw that error); the type that's being deserialized is `net.corda.core.flows.NotarizationPayload`, while when I call the flow with Postman, the type that's being deserialized is: `java.util.List`.

**Initiating Flow**

```
List result = hostSession.sendAndReceive(List.class, name).unwrap(it -> it);
```

**Responding Flow**

```
String name = otherPartySession.receive(String.class).unwrap(it -> it);
List accounts = getServiceHub()
        .cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class).accountInfo(name);
StateAndRef<AccountInfo> accountStateAndRef = (StateAndRef<AccountInfo>)accounts.stream()
        .filter(acc -> ((StateAndRef<AccountInfo>)acc).getState().getData().getHost()
                .equals(getOurIdentity()))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
List result = new ArrayList();
if (accountStateAndRef != null)
    result.add(accountStateAndRef);
otherPartySession.send(result);
```

Comment: The "Payload invalid" exception should have a cause attached to it that came from the deserialisation.  What's the exception there?

Comment: @fowlerrr: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo: Interface net.corda.core.contracts.LinearState requires a field named linearId but that isn't found in the schema or any superclass schemas`

Comment: @fowlerrr, actually your question hinted what could be the problem; I'll post an answer shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `cordapp "$accounts_release_group:accounts-contracts:$accounts_release_version"` dependency in my local node.